# Liouville's theorem application

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that $f(x+iy) = u(x,y) +iv(x,y)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{C}$ and $u$ is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$.  Use Liouville's theorem to show that $f$ is constant on $\mathbb{C}$.
>
> Hint: what can you say about $e^f$?

I understand the idea of the liouville's theorem but don't know how to apply it on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the hint:
$$
e^{u+iv} = e^u(\cos v+ i\sin v)
$$
and since $v$ is real, that trigonometric factor is bounded.  So if $u$ is bounded, then the whole thing is bounded.